# Storage of ids of selected image

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a group of images with divs 0, 1, etc. So at a certain point I need to have the id's of the selected images `'img.selected' (with  $(this).toggleClass('selected');)` being executed some lines before.

So I use `$('img.selected').attr('id')` and it does indeed return the id of the image, but with the small problem, that when I click another image later on with id greater that the last one, it return the smaller id.

So for example I click image 3, it return 3, then I click image 2 and I get 2 in return, then I click 0 and I get 0, **but** then I click 6, I still got 0, and so on. It always return the smaller of the divs.

Any suggestions about why it does that and how to work it around?

Comment: I think you need an array of selected image.

Comment: Sounds to me like you're not removing the `.selected` class when making a new selection.

Comment: So you have more than one element with class selected at once? If ya, map it to get an array: `var ids = $('img.selected').map(function(){return this.id;}).get()` That's said, you should provide a concrete example replicating your issue, it's not clear what are you expecting here, e.g, what is the context of `this`???

Comment: Jop, the removeclass actually did it! Sorry for the stupid post.

Comment: Have you tried, which I answered? :)

Answer (score 1):

click image 3:

```
<img id=1></img>
<img id=2></img>
<img id=3 class="selected"></img>
```

in this case:

`$('img.selected').attr('id')` return id=3

then click image 1:

```
<img id=1 class="selected"></img>
<img id=2></img>
<img id=3 class="selected"></img>
```

`$('img.selected').attr('id')` always return id=1

Answer (score 0):

Because browser starts checking from smaller id (created first) divs. So it finds 0 before 6 while  it looks like working fine then going from 3 to 2 to 1 to 0. Remove the selected from the selected before adding it to another as James said.

Answer (score 0):

Try this or other method which removes `selected` class first before click:

```
$("img").each(function(item, index){
    $(this).removeClass('selected');
});
```